# List of foreign keys in Entity Framework Core using SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I want to implement Related Pages structure that one page have a list of other pages related to it. But I could't figure out if it is possible. Now I have the structure like this:

```
public class Page
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UrlName { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedPages> RelPages1 { get; set; }
}
public class RelatedPages
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public Page Page { get; set; }
    // I would like this to be the list of related page IDs 
    public List<int> RelPagesID { get; set; }
    public List<Page> RelPages { get; set; }
}
```

And here is OnModelCreating method in my DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedPages>()
                        .HasOne(x => x.Page)
                        .WithMany(x => x.RelPages1)
                        .HasForeignKey(x => x.PageID);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to do a recursive selection such that EF will load all the records in turn for the same table then I don't think this is possible. Otherwise your structure should work fine.

Comment: I want to add multiple IDs to `RelPagesID` in RelatedPages like 1, 3, 5 and to have Pages with these IDs in the List `RelPages`. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think RelPagesID can be populated like this by entity framework it would populate the List<Page> however,

You can just project like this
Pages.Where(p=>p.Page.Id == 3433)
This will give you a list of the related pages ids.